# How to filter posts by category INSIDE the loop

Tags: loop, sort

I'm trying to sort my posts like so:

```
CATEGORY 1 
- post title
- post title

CATEGORY 2
- post title
- post title
```

I have no problem achieving this with a custom query:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'hide_emppty' => 1,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'taxonomy' => 'course_category'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

    <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>

    <?php $courses = new WP_Query( "post_type=courses&posts_per_page=-1&course_term=term-fall&course_category=" . $category->slug);  ?>
    <?php if ( $courses->have_posts() ) : while ( $courses->have_posts() ) : $courses->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, what I need to do is sort posts that come from a plugin-generated query (I have no (?) control over it) - so this needs to happen inside a normal `if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts())` loop.

Is this even possible? The posts from this query are all of correct post type and course_term custom taxonomy, just need to get sorted by course_category taxonomy like above.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you tried using functions that get the terms instead of using get_categories?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. The above code works, I just need to do something else with the same result, as explained later in the post.

Comment: This is sort of an issue of sorting default WP loop's posts by category vs. doing so with a custom query. How would I do it inside a default loop?

Comment: You can't really sort inside a Loop. You need to alter the query itself or sort the results from the query before the Loop starts. Without more information I don't know what the recommend. Try to add more detail. How does the plugin work? What does its output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Got a quite radical solution :

```
function wpse_102497_modify_query_order( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_102497_modify_query_order' );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I agree with this solution - use filters and hooks to alter the order - once you are in the loop, it's too late to re-order the post items, without a pretty comprehensive `array_map`